# Getting Fingerprint AIO err: plugin_not_installed when i try to run the application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have an Ionic 3 app with "cordova-android": "^8.1.0".

I want to implement biometrics in my app with **@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio**

I have installed the plugin for my Ionic 3 app using the following commands-

**ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio**

**npm install --save @ionic-native/fingerprint-aio@4**

But when i try to build and run the app on my device it says

*Installing "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio" for android*

*Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 8.1.0, failed version requirement: >=9.0.0*

*Skipping 'cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio' for android*

I have changed the minimum sdk version in my config.xml to "23"

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

These are the values from my package.json

**"@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^4.20.0",**

**"cordova-android": "^8.1.0",**

**"cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^4.0.1",**

What version of the plugin is supported on Ionic 3?
Please guide me in this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried upgradng Cordova? "npm i cordova@latest"

Comment: I tried that but it gives me lots of errors so i skipped that

Comment: Please add the error log with your question. There might be some issue with cordova 9.0.0 compatibility with other plugins

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my cordova android version to 9.0.0 and now the plugin works fine.